# Python Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison in list

Tags: python, list, recursion, runtime-error

So here is the construct

```
#list1 and list2
list1 = [(True,), (True,)]
list2 = [(True,), (True,)]
#Transformation
list1[0] = list2
list1[1] = list1
list2[0] = list1
list2[1] = list2
```

Which gives:

```
#Result
#list1 = [ list2 , list1 ]
#list2 = [ list1 , list2 ]
```

When I run this code

```
>>>list2 in list1
True
>>>list1 in list1
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I believe the error occurs because getting the actual value of list1 for comparison results in an endless loop. However, list2 does not result in this error despite being constructed similarly.

So my question is, why is there a discrepancy in the error? Shouldn't "list2 in list1" cause an error too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
list = [1,2,3]
list.append(list)
```

it doesn't do this:

```
list.append([1,2,3])
```

That'd be creating a new list. It appends a "reference" to the list. This is because copying things that are not fundamental types is rarely what you want to do (PHP jab removed)

So say you do

```
list.append(4)
```

Now:

```
print(list[3][4])
```

will show 4, as the 3rd thing (4th really as they start at zero) is the list reference, we look at that's 4th (5th) which is the 4 we just appended. So

```
list is list[3]
```

Is true, they refer to the same actual lits.

The recursion happens for the same reason you can't do `print(list)`, it starts looking, then it ends up looking in itself endlessly.

It ends because Python has a max stack depth, which is by default 500 I think, you can have a function call a function call a function ..... 497 more times. Yours will never terminate so hits this wall.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I still don't get why list2 in list1 does not result in error.

Comment: Okay if I give you `list1=[list2,list1]` and you search for `list2` in it, you find it immediately. It never tries to see if it is in `list1` (as in `list1[1]` - the second thing) @user3218450

Comment: Going by that reasoning list1 in list1 should not result in error right? since list1[1] is list1

Comment: You can get the [recursion limit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit): `sys.getrecursionlimit()`. You can change the max by running `sys.setrecursionlimit()`. My default recursion limit is 1000, but it may be machine specific.

Comment: @user3218450 what do you expect to happen, if I asked you to define "x in y" for a list y what would you do, say "check if list itself is x" or "for each one of the things in y see if x is in it".

Comment: I would " for each of the thing in y check if thing == x" which requires a definite value for thing and x. But since list1 and list2 are defined recursively, I should not be able to get a definite value for comparison. I see your solution as " for each of the thing in y check if id(thing) == id(x)"

Comment: @user3218450 what if "==" isn't defined?

Comment: @user3218450 what if there's a list in a list, so for example is "3 in [[3]]"? they're containers. Lets take a house, is something in the house, well if something is in a room of the house, it's also in the house. By your logic, a thing in the room of a house isn't in the house!

Comment: I would use "is" instead. Return True if "thing is x", else "check if item(i) in x is item(i) in thing" until end of recursion. If this is right, I think I got my answer?

Comment: @user3218450 trust me when I say you have not seen the light. You.... I dunno what you're trying to do but it looks awful (lists of tuples of true?!) - learn more and it'll make sense.

Comment: Well its just a thought experiment to further my understanding, no real purpose..

Comment: @user3218450 build real things. Learn about abstraction and inheritance and object orientated programming, use wxWidgets (wxPython) and create windows by subclassing, do useful stuff! You'll further your understanding on the way.